# understanding css important keyword in this example

Tags: css

in my html I have

```
<div id="mainNewsBody" class="news">
    <a class="readMore" href="/News/Details/1">read more ...</a>
</div>
```

I tried to style read more ... snipper with this css

```
#mainNewsBody .news .readMore a{
    color: #7F0609;
}
```

to actually apply this style I have to use `!important` keyword in color property.
I know that this !important keyword force to use that property but I do not understand why that is the case here, because I explicitly told to match on particular id with particular class element and inside that element to mach link.

Can someone englight me.

Thanks

Comment: Read up on [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors), you'll understand where you've gone wrong. The styles and structure you've mentioned do not match the situation you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `a.readMore` instead of `.readMore a` (the first case would search for an element with class `.readMore` and append the CSS to any children `a`-elements)

and `#mainNewsBody .news` should be `#mainNewsBody.news` (you should 'concatenate' the id and class since they refer to the same element)

making a total of `#mainNewsBody.news a.readMore`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqjdE/)

**EDIT**

I see many notes on simplifying your css to just classes. This really depends on what you're trying to accomplish. If you're working with a huge CSS file, I'd recommend specifying as strict as possible. This to prevent any CSS being applied on places where you don't want it to.

`a { }` for example will mess with all your links, `a.news { }` will only mess with `a class='news'`

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
.news .readMore {
    color: #7F0609;
}
```

There's no need to call for id and class name for the same element.

Answer (score 1):

It'd the specificity which is troubling you, the more elements class id you have in your selector, more specific your selector is.

So for example

```
.class a {

}
```

is more specific than just

```
a {

}
```

Just see to it that you do not have a more specific selector, if you've than you need to make the current one more specific or use `!important` declaration as you stated.

In the above snippet this is incorrect

```
#mainNewsBody .news .readMore a
```

It will search for an element having class `news` inside an element having an id `mainNewsBody` which is not true in your case so either use this

```
#mainNewsBody a.readMore { 
/* This will be more specific than the below one 
   as you are using id here and not class */
    color: #7F0609;
}
```

Or use

```
.news a.readMore {
    color: #7F0609;
}
```

Comment: Your last example will search for an `a` inside `.readMore` while `.readMore` IS `a` in OP's example :)

Comment: @Aquillo Ya that reminds me you answered nicely so voted you :)

Answer (score 1):

Ozan is right, remove the "mainNewsBody" ID from the CSS if it's not absolutely necessary.

```
.news .readMore a{
color: #7F0609;}
```

If you want to be really specific and need to include the ID in the CSS selector remove the space from in-front of ".news"

```
#mainNewsBody.news .readMore a{
color: #7F0609;}
```

[CSS Tricks - Multiple Class ID Selectors](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

CSS rules marked !important take precedence over later rules. !important ensures that this rule has precedence.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your code is generating inline css for the `a` element, or you have another less specific definition for `a` element with `!important` keyword somewhere else.

Inline styles have priority higher than styles defined outside the element. To overcome the inline style or a style with `!important` keyword by a less specific definition, you need to define it by the keyword `!important` and a more specific definition.